# Most Efficient way to find top 100 elements from a Map

Tags: java, performance, sorting, dictionary, guava

I've been using this method to get the top 100 elements by count from a Map. Does anyone know how guava implements these?

```
    Ordering<String> valueComparator = 
       Ordering.natural().onResultOf(
         Functions.forMap(WordCounts)).compound(Ordering.natural());

    ImmutableSortedMap<String, Integer> SortedWordCounts = 
      ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(WordCounts, 
        Collections.reverseOrder(valueComparator));
    Map<String, Integer> TopWordCounts = 
    SortedWordCounts.headMap(SortedWordCounts.keySet().asList().
         get(100));
```

I didn't see much detail here
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gwt-javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html

I'm trying to think whether this is inefficient and whether I should use a top k algorithm like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm
To run an algorithm like that I'd have to convert the map to an array, and then likely back to a map, which makes me think it might not be worth it.

Comment: Top 100 of what exactly? Keys, or values?

Comment: both. in this case i get a view of the first 100 keys/values of the map since its immutable and sorted

Comment: though it would be easy enough to retrieve the values if i have the 100 keys, so its not too important

Comment: Check the source code yourself: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r09/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.java

Comment: that's quite helpful, though still not really sure how efficient it is, but i guess i can try profiling it in comparison with a top k algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if you're storing counts with Guava, you should really be using a `Multiset`.  If you do that, then you can use the convenient method `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst` to get a multiset in highest-to-lowest count order.

To get the top 100 elements like this, you could write

```
Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(multiset).elementSet().asList().subList(0, 100);
```

which returns you an `ImmutableList` of the top 100 elements, in a single line.

If you want to use a fancier selection algorithm, Guava already has that implemented as [`Ordering.greatestOf`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#greatestOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) and `Ordering.leastOf`.  These use a fancy-pants variation on the selection algorithm you cited that doesn't require an O(n) copy of the collection into a big array, but it still runs in linear time.

If you need both the elements and the counts, you should really not try to use an `ImmutableSortedMap` or anything like that with a comparator that looks up the elements; you should copy into a new `Multiset`.  The way I would write this, if efficiency were my top priority, would be:

```
Ordering<Multiset.Entry<E>> highestCountFirst = 
  new Ordering<Multiset.Entry<E>>() {
    @Override public int compare(Multiset.Entry<E> e1, Multiset.Entry<E> e2) {
      return Ints.compare(e1.getCount(), e2.getCount());
    }
  };
ImmutableMultiset.Builder<E> top100Builder = ImmutableMultiset.builder();
for (Multiset.Entry<E> topEntry : 
       highestCountFirst.greatestOf(multiset.entrySet(), 100)) {
  top100Builder.addCopies(topEntry.getElement(), topEntry.getCount());
}
return top100Builder.build();
```

Comment: well those are all quite nice in terms of simplicity. (you actually wrote the one i'm asking about now too haha). but i'm most interested right now in speed and presumably those all do the same thing just in less words. however, are they more efficient for any reason?

Comment: also sorry for not being clear but i need both the keys and counts, not just the keys

Comment: thank you that is extremely thorough! but could you explain why an immutable multiset is more efficient than an immutable sorted map? plus after this i'm doing some filtering with blacklists/key-to-key mappings etc.. so i would want to convert back to a map after using a multiset anyway

Comment: A `Multiset` is just _the thing you should use_ when you're counting occurrences of things.  The [Guava wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) has some explanation on why `Multiset` has a better API for these problems.  (You should be able to rewrite most of the things you mention in terms of `Multiset`, too; ask another SO question if you have problems with that.)

Comment: hmm i see interesting..so insertions/deletions are O(1)? at first i assumed multiset was just like a basic list of pairings but looks like its more powerful than that

Comment: For a `HashMultiset`, yes.  For a `TreeMultiset`, it's O(log n).

Comment: elementSet().asList() - The Set Interface doesn't have this method, right?

Comment: Ah, no, you'll have to cast it to ImmutableSet.  (That's a bug we're fixing.)